# NodeJS: Cookie is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I'm trying to make a simple GET request to my localhost:8080.
When I make the GET request with Postman, I set a simple cookie. Now, in the main file, I've:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
app.use(cookieParser()); 
const app_router = require('./routes/router');

app.use("/api", app_router);
app.use(express.static('public'));


app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log('Outdoor Localization GNSS middleware.');
});
```

In routes/router.js I have:

```
var express = require('express')
const router = express.Router();
const axios = require('axios');
const url = 'http://10.10.0.145:80/api'

router.use(express.json());


router.get('/*', function (request, response) { 
   console.log(request.Cookie)

    axios
    .get(request_url)
    .then(res => {
    console.log(request.Cookie)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error)
    })
});
```

The problem is that request.Cookie always return undefined...why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be accessing the property `request.cookies` instead of `request.Cookie`

Comment: For more info: http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.cookies